# Antlr 4: Is getting this form of output possible?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Within the context of scanning, what do i need to override, extend, listen to, visit to be able to print out this form of informative output when my text is being scanned?

```
-- Example output only ---------
DEBUG ... current mode: DEFAULT_MODE
DEBUG ... matching text '#' on rule SHARP ; pushing and switching to DIRECTIVE_MODE
DEBUG ... matching text 'IF" on rule IF ; pushing and switching to IF_MODE
DEBUG ... matching text '          ' on rule WS; skipping
DEBUG ... no match for text %
DEBUG ... no match for text &

DEBUG ... mathcing text '\r\n' on rule EOL; popping mode; current mode: DIRECTIVE_MODE
...
```

thanks

Comment: As far as I understand you want to see debug messages of the lexer state. I think this is impossible, because the lexer grammar is transformed into a DFA. The DFA optimizes the state transitions, such that they are efficient, but do no longer correspond to grammar rules.

Comment: Maybe you should post your grammar. The example output points to the fact that you try to do too much in the lexer und not in the parser. In the parser it is easier to debug or to place debug outputs.

Comment: That is correct. I am looking for a way to print out descriptive debug messages while lexing is being done. 
It doesn't matter what my grammar is. I want to know what is being scanned, what the result was, what  mode was pushed , what is the current mode, and so on

Comment: Lexers supporting such output would not be efficient (I do not know whether ANTLR supports it, but nobody should use such a lexer in production). Yet, handling conditional blocks (rule IF) is usually done as parser rule. Your problem (and your language design) will probably much better if you favor parser rules of mode switching. If you want to keep your grammar private, I cannot give you hints where transformation would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a lot simpler than I thought.
You just need to subclass the generated Lexer and override methods such as popMode(), pushMode() to get the printout you want. If you do this you should also override emit() methods as well to get properly sequential and contextual information.

Here's an example in C#:

```
class ExtendedLexer : MyGeneratedLexer
{
public ExtendedLexer(ICharStream input)
    : base(input)  { }
public override int PopMode()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Mode is being popped: Line: {Line} Column:{Column} ModeName: {ModeNames[ModeStack.Peek()]}");
    return base.PopMode();
}
public override void PushMode(int m)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Mode is being pushed: Line: {Line} Column:{Column} ModeName: {ModeNames[m]}");
    base.PushMode(m);
}
public override void Emit(IToken t)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[@{t.TokenIndex},{t.StartIndex}:{t.StopIndex}, <{Vocabulary.GetSymbolicName(t.Type)}> = '{t.Text}']");
    base.Emit(t);
}
```

}

And the output would be something like:

```
Mode is being pushed: Line: 4 Column:3 ModeName: IF_MODE
[@-1,163:165, <IF> = '#IF']
Mode is being pushed: Line: 4 Column:4 ModeName: CONDITION_MODE
[@-1,166:166, <LPAREN> = '(']
[@-1,167:189, <EXP> = '@setStartDateAndEndDate']
Mode is being popped: Line: 4 Column:28 ModeName: IF_MODE
[@-1,190:190, <RPAREN> = ')']
```